# Automatically downloading & installing cookbooks on a vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, virtualbox, vagrantfile, berkshelf

I'm trying to create a Vagrant box that'll install some services when I run `vagrant up`.

For that purpose, I'm making use of these services:

- Oracle VirtualBox
- Chef Solo provisioner
- Berkshelf
- Vagrant Berkshelf Plugin

I'm using Berkshelf in order to handle cookbook dependencies.

The issues arise with certain cookbooks, which simply won't install.
Currently I'm trying to install nginx, from the cookbook I found on Chef Supermarket - [nginx cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/nginx).

**Berksfile:**

```
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"
cookbook "nginx"
```

**Vagrantfile:**

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "CentOS-6.5-minimal-0.1.1"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
    config.vm.hostname = "vagrant"
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]

    config.berkshelf.enabled = true
    config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
      chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks"]
      chef.add_recipe "nginx"
    end

end
```

I tried running `vagrant provision` with a combination of `vagrant reload` and shutting the box down and running `vagrant up`

The closest I've gotten to determining the cause of the problem is **[this stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/04scFB5N)**, I've gotten when running `vagrant provision`.

Any help for resolving this will be much appreciated.

Comment: @justMiles `kitchen` is meant for testing purposes, not full time use

Answer (score 0):

The key issue here is you are using the Chef version that ships in Hashcorp's default boxes (`Starting Chef Client, version 11.8.2`). This version is too old to use the current `nginx` cookbook. You probably want to use the bento boxes which don't include a baked in version of Chef and then install it via Vagrant's omnibus support.

Comment: Are you suggesting that chef was preinstalled in the box I used? and also, how can I know in the future whether a certain cookbook can be used with my version of chef?

Comment: most certainly chef is already installed, you can set `chef.version = "12.10.40"` in your vagrantfile, it will upgrade your chef version in the VM

Comment: With newer Chef we added a `chef_version` field to the cookbook metadata but it's relatively new so not all cookbooks support it. Usually the best way is to check the README for each cookbook: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/compat_resource In there you can see it supports 12.0+.